# transfer file from server to home computer

Tags: server, scp, transfer

I have a text file on the server(linux) at work and now I am at home. I am a putty user. to connect to the server from home I have to connect to another server (which means I can connect to the server at work, indirectly from home) so I can't use scp command or winscp to transfer or copy my file to my computer at home. does anybody know that how I can transfer or copy my file from the server at work to my home computer(windows system)? thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and therefore it's off-topic here. You may be able to get help at a different [se] site, such as [su]. You should always check the help center at any site before posting a question there, to make sure you've selected the most appropriate site for your question. You can find the guidelines for this site in our [help].

Answer (score -2):

Since it's a text file, putty's `capture` feature should work for you.  In putty, the capture feature is in Category Session → Logging.  Just specify the local filename that you want to save the text file to on your Windows machine, then use Linux's `cat` command to cat the file on the remote Linux host.  With `capture` enabled in putty, it should save the output of the cat command (i.e. the contents of the text file) to a file locally on your Windows machine.